# Project not found on adding exisiting project in TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have two different solutions in a TFS Track.
I have defined entities in one project and I added that project by using add existing project
in the second solution.
It is building successfully when i right click and build,
but when I am queuing the build, I am getting this error

```
C:\Builds\3\..\Namespace.BusinessEntities.csproj is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your .sln file. You will find full path of the projects. Make sure the .csproj file is found at the path mentioned in the .sln file.

Open your .sln file in notepad or Notepad++ or anyother text editor.